# How to remove object from array in Parse with Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have an array of items in a column in Parse.

I am able to fetch that array with the code :

```
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Names")

    query.whereKey("date", greaterThan: NSDate())
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object, error) -> Void in
        if object != nil
        {
            if(object!.count != 0)
            {
                for messageObject in object! {
                   self.arrayNames = ((messageObject as! PFObject)["arrayNames"] as? [String])!
                }
            } else {
                 print("No Objects")
            }
         } 
     }  // self.arrayNames = ["Aruna", "Bala", "Chitra", "Divya"]
```

In this I want to delete an single item and again save it to the parse.

I can delete it locally as `removeAtIndex` but how can I remove that from Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have retrieved your array, remove the one item you do not want, reassign the new array to the retrieved object and then save.

Answer (score 0):

In the names, if I wanted to delete Aruna,

```
self.arrayNames.removeAtIndex(0)
```

Then to update this array in Parse,

```
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Names")

query.whereKey("date", greaterThan: NSDate())
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (object, error) -> Void in
    if object != nil {
        object!.setValue(self.arrayNames, forKey: "arrayNames")
        object!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
              (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
              if(success) {
                  print("Success")                  
              } else {
                  print("Error")
              }
        }
    }
}
```

I found that, i cant directly delete an single element from an array in a column in Parse. So I am updating that array with my local array. It works!

Answer (score -1):

If you read the docs you will find [one of the delete methods](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#task_Deleting%20an%20Object) useful such as `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:`

```
object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // do whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: i want to remove only one item in an array in a column in Parse. `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock` will completely remove the array in the column.